# Python and PostgreSQL - GeomFromText

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm a Python learner,

I'm trying to insert geometry records into PostgreSQL.

If I tried the query without the geometry column, it works fine and all data inserted successfully.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO taxi (userid,carNum) SELECT '"+str(msg['UserID'])+"',"+str(msg['CarNumber']))
```

Once I try to add the geometry records, nothing happens! execution ends without errors but nothing being inserted into DB.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO taxi (position,userid,carNum) SELECT GeomFromText('POINT("+str(float(msg['longitude']))+" "+str(float(msg['latitude']))+")',4326),'"+str(msg['UserID'])+"',"+str(msg['CarNumber']))
```

Couldn't figure out what I'm missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit the data to the database.

Check the documentation of psycopg2 http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Follow those steps

```
>>> import psycopg2

# Connect to an existing database
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")

# Open a cursor to perform database operations
>>> cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute a command: this creates a new table
>>> cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")

# Pass data to fill a query placeholders and let Psycopg perform
# the correct conversion (no more SQL injections!)
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)",
...      (100, "abc'def"))

# Query the database and obtain data as Python objects
>>> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test;")
>>> cur.fetchone()
(1, 100, "abc'def")

# Make the changes to the database persistent
>>> conn.commit()

# Close communication with the database
>>> cur.close()
>>> conn.close()
```